# Pixelate Faces in the VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I need to hide faces from videos I make. I've found tutorials on blurring, which are great, but the render times are too long to be practical.

So in place of that, is there a way to pixelate the face in using the Video Sequence Editor?

Comment: @zeffii I would keep it. If you can find a way to do it in the VSE you can add that.

Comment: Hello guys,

I am editing my videos, I followed youtube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_06cWLUZ_Bg 
but I was thinking if it would render faster if face would be pixelated, 
like this: http://lorrie.cranor.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/IMG_2373-pixelated-150x150.jpg 
or this: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_Eiwce13X738/SiZGDgKfqMI/AAAAAAAAGj4/G10l2ANuIX4/s400/Pixel.Face.JPG

@zeffii The link you posted is blur? I need pixels.

Thank you

Comment: like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/vIDcm.png  ?

Comment: @zeffii hey, that is the effect I'd like to try, but in video sequence editor. Do you have some steps for noob like me? Thank you

Comment: unfortunately I don't know the VSE enough to help! but i'm surprised that you think the pixelation effect is a slow compositor effect..

Comment: @zeffii oi, well the area of pixel is 1x1, and i scale it to e.g.100x100, so my farmer logic thinks it is less to calculate than blur, where every pixel is different... So for the time being, i made a picture of skin colors and blured that, and put pisture behind video, so it renders normaly fast.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a VES transform effect first to shrink the image...

[image: Pixelate in VSE]

Make sure to set interpolation to off.

[image: Shrink VSE]

Next and another Transform effect onto the first, and reverse the scale. Enlarging the image. Make sure that Interpolation is off again.

[image: Enlarge VSE Pixelated]

Answer (score 5):

I added a pixelate function to the Blender Addon [VSE_Transform_Tools](https://github.com/doakey3/VSE_Transform_Tools) using [3pointedit's method](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/102951/31751). You could download the addon and use the <kbd>P</kbd> key to apply pixelation, then set the severity of the pixelation with the tool that pops up.

For a stationary subject, I recommend using the crop tool that also comes with the addon to crop out a face.

[image]

For moving subjects, I recommend tracking, then applying a mask.

[image]

Comment: Hey thats a nice use! I haven't looked at the Transform tool in ages. Glad the crop is better these days

Answer (score 0):

- The material texture is better suited to the task of quantization.
- The animation of the 3D View is better suited to specifying location of video manipulation.
- The VSE has limited effects compared to the compositor.

[image]

The image above was quite legible in the original and has been quantized or pixelated in Blender.

[image]

In the Blender screen capture above.  Note the settings.

- Interpolation false.
- Filter FELINE
- Probes 1
- Filter Size 20.

Explore Probes and Filter to suit your taste.

In 3D view the material texture can sample images at reduced resolution to produce pixelation.  You can 
create a moving object such as a sphere which might be positioned to cover a face and produce a "mask".

So two texture planes and one mask object are indicated, perhaps in different render layers.

In the Compositor phase of rendering, the mask image can then be used to compose the original video with pixelated video selectively with an alpha over node.

This explanation is a reduction.  I cannot comment on speed characteristics of your machine.

Comment: To use this technique in the VSE you could add a plane with image mapped then add it's scene strip in your master timeline (using an alternate scene) if you stack the original complete media strip and the scene strip (starting at the same frame) you could meta strip them together. Turn the scene strip off for speed. Use a mask modifier to cut out a shape.