# Rendering same scene multiple times? (changed by frame change handler)

Tags: python, rendering, video-sequence-editor

This is a follow-up question to my [previous post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/122637/rendering-large-amount-of-short-videos-with-different-generated-animation).

After a certain learning period I was able to produce the generated scenes I wanted. It looks similar to this gif (credit to @batFINGER):
[image: gif of same scene changing on every loop]

In short: I wanted to generate a short video of a camera following a license plate, the important part is to produce thousands of videos like this with randomized license number and camera angles.

I generated it (as suggested by @batFINGER) by using a frame change handler, on every first frame of the scene the handler changes the license plate and randomize the camera angles. Because the scene loops, each loop I get different results.

Now I have a scene that when I press play it shows something similar to the gif above.

My question is how I render from this scene multiple videos with different parameters in each?

I tried searching by my own but I probably don't know the correct terminology and couldn't find anything useful.

Additionally, it would be really helpful if someone could tell me if the rendering speed can be faster than the framerate? I plan on generating low resolution videos so my workstation will be able to render the videos much faster than the framerate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a bit of searching with different keywords I found two very useful resources:

[A post in this forum with very similar request (I'm surprised I didn't find it in the first search).](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72734/how-to-programatically-render-multiple-times-with-different-materials-each)

[Also, a nice tutorial with some basic explanation that helped me.](http://www.blenderist.com/b/?p=131)